# List taking up 13 gigs of ram with 127 mil entries: how?

Tags: python, list

I'm working through a programming challenge involving quick processing and large data.  I'm trying to generate a list of possible permutations of a number range and then search through them.

Code:

```
def generate_list(numA, numB):
    combo = list(range(0, numB))
    permutation_list = list(itertools.permutations(combo, numA))
    print("initial dictionary length: " + len(permutation_list))
```

The problem is that when A is 6 and B is 25, my program slows down immensely and takes up a huge amount of RAM.  It peeked at around 13 gigs.  The length of the listis around 127 mil and each object is of length 6.  That should put the usage at around 750 megs of memory, not 13 gigs.  What's going on?

Edit: The data is just numbers.  So [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,6],...]

Comment: Which challenge is it? Any way to access the description and the data?

Comment: The data is just numbers.  So [[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,4,6],...]

Comment: I made an error.  I meant list wherever I typed dictionary

Comment: I would guess the challenge here is to avoid creation of so many objects in the first place - you should rethink an exhaustive creation of your permutations.

Comment: Is there a way to add a filter to the permutations function or would it likely just be easier to rewrite the function?

Comment: Keep the iterator from itertools, rather than casting to `list`. You can always loop over this to count/processes the items

Comment: @Chris_Rands is correct, use it as a generator - for example `z = itertools.permutations(range(0,25), 6)`, then we can eg test how many sum to 83: `sum(map(lambda x: sum(x) == 83, z))`. Using a smarter algorithm tailored to your exact problem is still probably better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of a list or a tuple is a pointer. And has a size of either 4 or 8 bytes. The following assumes the latter. Just counting the pointers in the list and tuples accounts for half of the space used. The rest is likely the object header which is about 48 bytes. This yields the formula:

```
(48+8+(8*6)) * 127000000 == 13208000000
```

which is about your 13 gigabytes.

I would suggest doing anything possible to avoid generating that complete permutation.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured I had to do it another way, but it's always good to know why I was failing, not just that I failed.

Answer (score -1):

An example of how you might output the entire list of permutations might be as follows:

```
import itertools

def combo(b):
    for combination in range(0, b):
        yield combination

def generate_list(numA, numB):
    for l in itertools.permutations(combo(numB), numA):
        yield list(l), len(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    total_length = int()
    with open('permutations', 'w+') as f:
        f.write('[')
        for permutation in generate_list(6, 25):
            data, length = permutation
            total_length += length
            f.write(str(data) + ', ')
        f.write(']\n')
    print("initial dictionary length: " + str(total_length))
```

I've turned your code into two separate generators. One that gives the combination, another that gives the permutation.

You can calculate the entire thing without a `MemoryError` and write them to a file. A *very* large file. Or you could just print it to stdout, up to you.

It will also tell you the length at the end, without requiring massive amounts of memory to do so.